# call a repository in a different repository symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a question about repositories: Is it possible to use

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getEntityManager();
     $range = $em->getRepository('***Bundle:entityA')
                ->find($id);
```

in the repository of an entityB  ????

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your repository class you already have access to entity manager, so you just need to do:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('***Bundle:entityA')->find($id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following:

**Case A:**
You need to query 2 Entities, no relation to each other.
Use 2 repositories, 2 queries

```
$range1 = $em->getRepository('***Bundle:entityA')->find($id);
$range2 = $em->getRepository('***Bundle:entityB')->find($id);
```

**Case B:**
You need to query 2 Entities, related to each other, or depending on each other.
Use 1 Repository, write a custom repository function, join them, or select on multiple tables

```
$range = $em->getRepository('***Bundle:entityA')->findAjoinedB();

 class EntityArepository extends EntityRepository
 {

   public function findAjoinedB(){
       $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('entityA')
             ->leftJoin('entityA.entityB_id', 'entityB')
             ->where(....
             ....;

       return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I need  $range = $em->getRepository('***Bundle:entityA')             ->find($id); inside the entityB repository. @DerStoffel

Comment: To answer that properly I would need your usecase, and relation of the entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you like more to inject dependencies, declare your repositories as services so you can inject one to use it inside the other:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    repository.entity_a:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\EntityARepository
        factory: [@doctrine, getRepository]
        arguments:
            - AppBundle::EntityA

    repository.entity_b:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\EntityBRepository
        factory: [@doctrine, getRepository]
        arguments:
            - AppBundle::EntityB
        calls:
            - [setEntityARepository, [@repository.entity_a]]
```

in EntityBRepository.php you must have a setter (setEntityARepository) to a property to store the repository (i.e. $entityARepository).